# android studio как сменить эмулятор

Tags: android, android-studio

Как сменить эмулятор на второй, если поставил галку *не спрашивать больше, а запускать на ранее выбранном*?

Нужно снова окно выбора — на чем запускать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run -> Edit Configuration -> Вкладка: General -> Секция: Target Device -> отметить "Show chooser dialog" - показать диалог выбора устройства для запуска приложения.

либо

Run -> Edit Configuration -> Вкладка: General -> Секция: Target Device -> отметить "Emulator" и в выпадающем списке ниже выбрать другой эмулятор из имеющихся. Будет запускаться на выбранном эмуляторе.

Короткий путь: В тулбаре студии (значки с действиями сверху) кнопка со значком андроида и названием программы, левее зеленого треугольника запуска приложения. Нажать на нее - в выпавшем меню будет пункт "Edit configuration" - дальше так же, как выше.

[image: screenshot]